# Custom CSS of the Selectfield, Datepickers.... material-ui with redux-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

[image]I'm using from Material-UI with redux-form,  it looks like there is a div wrapping my label, input...(see picture) so i can't change the size of this div, the purpose of that it's to make these components responsive. on my col( materialize-css) i already make a test to remove materialize and put the system grid of material-UI nothing change... i create a css file and make a parent div with ( ex: width:80% !important) nothing change also.like you can see on the picture if i put col-md-2 this div wrapping doesn't fit with my grid. this is my code.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { reduxForm, Field } from "redux-form";
import { compose } from "redux";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import SelectField from "material-ui/SelectField";
import DatePicker from "material-ui/DatePicker";
import MenuItem from "material-ui/MenuItem";
import moment from "moment";


class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  onSubmit = formProps => {
    console.log(formProps);
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    const renderSelectField = ({
      input,
      label,
      meta: { touched, error },
      children,
      ...custom
    }) => (
      <SelectField
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
        children={children}
        {...custom}
      />
    );
    const renderDatePicker = ({
      input,
      defaultValue,
      meta: { touched, error },
      label,
    }) => (
      <DatePicker
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        value={input.value !== "" ? new Date(input.value) : null}
        onChange={(event, value) => {
          const formatDate = value;
          const responseDate = moment(formatDate).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
          input.onChange(responseDate);
        }}
      />
    );

    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col s12 m3">
                <Field
                  name="startDate"
                  type="text"
                  label="Pick up at"
                  component={renderDatePicker}
                  hintText="Checkin Date"
                  autoOk={true}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="col s12 m3">
                <Field
                  name="StartHour"
                  component={renderSelectField}
                  label="Hour"
                >
                  <MenuItem value={"Morning"} label="5 am - 12 pm" primaryText="Morning"/>
                  <MenuItem value={"Afternoon"}label="12 pm - 5 pm"primaryText="Afternoon"/>
                  <MenuItem value={"Evening"} label="5 pm - 9 pm" primaryText="Evening"/>
                  <MenuItem value={"Night"} label="9 pm - 5 am"  primaryText="Night" />
                </Field>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <button>here</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { auth: state.auth.authenticated };
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  reduxForm({ form: "search" })
)(SearchBar);
```